# Javascript number sorting on column table with commas as thousand separator

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

i have data from my db that used in table.
And I use some sorting javascript code to sort each column. But sorting result for number was not right (unordered number output).

```js
function sortTable(f, n) {
  var rows = $('#Product tbody  tr').get();

  rows.sort(function(a, b) {

    var A = getVal(a);
    var B = getVal(b);

    if (A < B) {
      return -1 * f;
    }
    if (A > B) {
      return 1 * f;
    }
    return 0;
  });

  function getVal(elm) {
    var v = $(elm).children('td').eq(n).text().toUpperCase();
    if ($.isNumeric(v)) {
      v = parseInt(v, 10);
    }
    return v;
  }

  $.each(rows, function(index, row) {
    $('#Product').children('tbody').append(row);
  });
}

var f_sort_price = 1;
var f_sort_quantity = 1;

$("#sort_price").click(function() {
  f_sort_price *= -1;
  var n = $(this).prevAll().length;
  sortTable(f_sort_price, n);
});

$("#sort_quantity").click(function() {
  f_sort_quantity *= -1;
  var n = $(this).prevAll().length;
  sortTable(f_sort_quantity, n);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="Product">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Product</th>
      <th id="sort_price">Price</th>
      <th id="sort_quantity">Quantity</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Graphic Card</td>
      <td>2,040</td>
      <td>1,493</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Wireless Router</td>
      <td>8,420</td>
      <td>2,272</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Mouse</td>
      <td>420</td>
      <td>493</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Monitor</td>
      <td>4.420</td>
      <td>874</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

and this is my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/imawof/bgkneo81/18/

i want to sort the price and quantity, with formated number in td. But i have no clue how to do right sorting it with formated number (commas thousand separator, dot decimal).

Comment: because you are sorting it as strings and not number. You need to remove the commas and convert it to a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first grab a copy of the data in the grid so that we can return to the default order when we toggle sorting off. See the `tableData` assignment below.

Now, to keep track of sorting, it would be better to assign data attributes to the table headers to keep track of sorting state.

For sorting, I wrote custom sorting logic as a jQuery plugin called `$.fn.sort`. This can be called on a table to change the sort order of the rows. The `tableData` is optional, but it helps give us back the original order.

```js
(function($) {
  $.parseNumeric = function(value) {
    return +value.replace(/[^-0-9.]/g, '').replace(/[,]/g, '')
  };
  
  $.isNumeric2 = function(value) {
    return !isNaN(+value.replace(/[$,]/g, ''));
  };
  
  $.tableDataToRows = function(data) {
    return data.map(row => $('<tr>')
      .append(row.map(col => $('<td>').text(col))));
  };
  
  $.fn.extractTableData = function() {
    return this.find('tbody tr').toArray()
      .map(tr => $(tr).find('td').toArray()
        .map(td => $(td).text()));
  };

  $.fn.sort = function(colIndex, direction, tableData) {
    var $tbody = this.find('tbody');
    var $rows = $tbody.find('tr');
    var sortDir = direction === 'asc' ? 1 : direction === 'desc' ? -1 : 0;
    var data = tableData ? $.tableDataToRows(tableData) : $rows.toArray();
    
    var sorted = data.sort((rowA, rowB) => {
      const a = $(rowA).find(`td:eq(${colIndex})`).text();
      const b = $(rowB).find(`td:eq(${colIndex})`).text();
      if (!b === '') return -1;
      if (!a === '') return 1;
      if ($.isNumeric2(a) && $.isNumeric2(b)) {
        return ($.parseNumeric(a) - $.parseNumeric(b)) * sortDir;
      }
      return a.localeCompare(b) * sortDir;
    });

    $tbody.empty().append(sorted);
  }
})(jQuery);

const nextSortDirection = (sortDirection) =>
  sortDirection
    ? sortDirection === 'asc' ? 'desc' : ''
    : 'asc';

const toggleSort = ($header) => {
  const sortDirection = nextSortDirection($header.data('sort-direction'));
  // Clear the existing sort
  $header.siblings().each(function() {
    $(this).attr('data-sort-direction', '');
    $(this).data('sort-direction', '');
  });
  // Change the sort for the current column
  $header.attr('data-sort-direction', sortDirection);
  $header.data('sort-direction', sortDirection);
  return sortDirection;
};

const $table = $('#Products');
const tableData = $table.extractTableData();

const onHeaderSort = (e) => {
  const $header = $(e.target);
  const $table = $header.closest('table');
  const field = $header.data('field');
  const colIndex = $header.prevAll().length; 
  const sortDirection = toggleSort($header);
  $table.sort(colIndex, sortDirection, tableData);
};

$table.find('th[data-sortable="true"]').on('click', onHeaderSort);
```

```css
:root {
  --header-color: #BBB;
  --row-color-even: #DDD;
  --row-color-odd: #FFF;
}

.styled-table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.styled-table {
  border: thin solid grey;
}

.styled-table th, .styled-table td {
  border: none;
}

.styled-table th, .styled-table td {
  padding: 0.25rem;
}

.styled-table th {
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 1.5rem;
  background: var(--header-color);
}

.styled-table tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: var(--row-color-even);
}

.styled-table tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background: var(--row-color-odd);
}

th[data-sortable]:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "\21D5";
  cursor: pointer;
  right: 0.25rem;
}
th[data-sort-direction="asc"]:after {
  content: "\21D1";
}
th[data-sort-direction="desc"]:after {
  content: "\21D3";
}

tbody td:nth-child(3),
tbody td:nth-child(4) {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="Products" class="styled-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-field="id" data-sortable="true" data-sort-direction="">ID</th>
      <th data-field="product" data-sortable="true" data-sort-direction="">Product</th>
      <th data-field="price" data-sortable="true" data-sort-direction="">Price</th>
      <th data-field="quantity" data-sortable="true" data-sort-direction="">Quantity</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Graphic Card</td>
      <td>$2,040.00</td>
      <td>1,493</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Wireless Router</td>
      <td>$8,420.00</td>
      <td>2,272</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Mouse</td>
      <td>$420.00</td>
      <td>493</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Monitor</td>
      <td>$4.42</td>
      <td>874</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Wow amazing works @Mr. Polywhirl, but i've question. In my table a used ajax for searching/filtering in each column, on success clear tbody and append the data from my query. the problem is after my searching/filtering and i'll try to sort with your plugins. But the result of sorting is all data showed up before filtering made. Do you have any sugesstion?

Comment: You will need to grab a copy of the data and store it upon refreshing the grid. Or scrape the data from the grid after you set it.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing commas(8,420) and decimal points (4.420).

If you intend to keep the ',' as visual seperators, you have to remove them in your sort function before converting them.
I also recommend parseFloat to keep the decimal points for your Prices.

```
function getVal(elm) {
           var v = $(elm).children('td').eq(n).text().toUpperCase();
           v = v.replace(",","");
            if ($.isNumeric(v)) {
                v = parseFloat(v);
            }
            return v;
        }
```

Comment: Thank You @Sven, you give me more enlightenment and power to continue this self training.

Comment: You may also like to separate the display and the data.  `<td data-value='1493'>1,493</td>`  then `var c = $(elm).children('td').eq(n);  return c.data("value") || c.text().toUpperCase()` - should also be quicker than multiple parseFloat.